# what is the purpose of -e in shell scripting in this code?

Tags: shell

```
echo "Enter file name "
            read filename
            while [ -e $filename ] ;
            do
                echo -e "\n\tFile is already exits !!"
                echo -e "Do u want to overwrite ? (y/n) :"
                read ch
                if [ $ch == "y" ];then
                    break  
                else    
                    echo -e "\n\tRe-enter file name :"
                    read filename
                fi
            done
```

Comment: Which particular `-e` are you asking about? For `test`, `-e` tests whether a file exists. For `echo`, `-e` enables the interpretation of backslash escapes.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: And remember that `[` is an alias for the [`test`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/test.1.html) command.

Comment: Or are you talking about the [`echo`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/echo.1.html) command? Please specify *which* `-e` you mean!

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 different occurrences of `-e` in the script.

In the case of `[ -e $filename ]`, the `[` is an alias for the command `test` so by referring to the documentation manual (try `man test`) we can see that the `-e` tests to see if the file specified exists:

> -e FILE  FILE exists

From the `echo` entry in the documentation manual (try `man echo` on your favourite terminal):

> -e     enable interpretation of backslash escapes

This means, instead of displaying a backslash as a character, backslash characters should be interpreted as an escape character.

Try running `echo "this is\n a test"` and `echo -e "this is\n a test"` to see the difference